# Does the certificate a SSL connection/state "points" to change if I load a new certificate in OpenSSL?

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, openssl

I am building an application that will enable users to connect to the same server. Rather than the application/device using its own certificate/private key, it is important to ensure that each user has their own certificate/private key to use for encryption.

Now I know, from the OpenSSL website documents, that their internal certificate store of OpenSSL can hold one certificate/key pair for the RSA cipher. My question is this:

Presume I have a SSL struct named **ssl1** that I created from my SSL_CTX where I didn't set the certificate/key to use in the SSL_CTX (thus not inheriting the certificate/key). I then go on to set the certificate/key for **ssl1** that is associated with some user. Then suppose I have another SSL struct named **ssl2** created from the same SSL_CTX. I then go on to set the certificate/key for **ssl2** that is associated with a different user than the first one.

If at this point I call the SSL_connect() API on **ssl1** will it use the certificate/key I set for **ssl2**? I ask since the store says it only holds one cert/key pair and I loaded the cert/key for **ssl2** last, thus I presume it would overwrite the one I loaded first for **ssl1**.

Thanks for reading my post. I appreciate any help/wisdom/pointers you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm confused about the implementation details you're asking for. Second, I can't think of a circumstance in which different keys would be useful unless you're trying to authenticate your users by their certificates -- which you're apparently not doing (users needing different encryption, not authentication.

I believe what you really want to do is establish your connections using settings that provide for [Perfect Forward Secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy). To do that, you want to use TLS ciphers all have names that start with TLS_DHE_. Those use Diffie-Hellman key exchanges, thus making the role of the server's key basically one of authentication of the server to users.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the SSL_CTX acts as template for SSL objects. So when you create new SSL object it inherits the properties/attributes of the SSL_CTX from which it is created. This is clearly mentioned [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_new.html#)

So for your question, both **ssl1** and **ssl2** objects will use their own certificate/key.